# list of string to display in table

Tags: python, string, type-conversion

I have a data:

```
list= """ID, Color, Brand, Price, Outstanding, Type
02, Blue, Audi, 200.12, True, 2
06, Red, BMW, 2357.13, True, 1
13, Black, Ford, 252676.12, False, 5"""
```

I need to display it in the table (ie, list of lists),(to not use dictionaries) and convert each string into native Python data type such as int, float, str, etc.
Conversion function should accept dataset as input argument and return the table..

I guess I need to use loops for that but I am new to Python and have no idea how to start.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using pandas. Pandas allows you to make dataframes of your arrays, lists, csv files, excel files etc.

Take a look at their documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/

There are a lot of youtube videos explaining this concept aswell.

Comment: The challenge is that I should not use any dictionaries to resolve this.

Comment: Oh i see, i miss understood. No imports you mean?

Comment: Try nested lists. A list in a list.

Comment: @SylwiaKmiec pandas is not implemented with dictionaries. If I remember well, it is implemented using numpy arrays. Is this a code challenge or something like that? Because in a real world app usually you would use pandas for this kind of operations.

Comment: I would love to use Pandas for this but got the following requirement:NOTE: You MUST NOT use third-party libraries such as numpy or pandas for this assignment, just basic Python

Comment: Then i would recommend tuples or nested lists.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this satisfies the requirement?

```
txt = 'ID, Color, Brand, Price, Outstanding, Type02, Blue, Audi, 200.12, True, 206, Red, BMW, 2357.13, True, 113, Black, Ford, 252676.12, False, 5'
# Remove the whitespaces first, then split the text by commas
l_txt = txt.replace(' ', '').split(',')

tb = []
for l in l_txt:
    tb.append([l])
```

Answer (score 0):

Without pandas, dict, just string and list.

```
def conv(cols):                 # only last 3 data requied conversion
    cols[3] = float(cols[3])
    cols[4] = True if (cols[4] == 'True') else False
    cols[5] = int(cols[5])
    return cols

dataset = []                    # create a list to store the data
lines = list.split('\n')        # split into lines from the text
for line in lines:              # for each line
    cols = line.split(', ')     # split into column from the line
    # print(cols)                 # display the columns of each line
    if not dataset:             # 1st row is title
        dataset.append(cols)    # just append it
        continue                # skip the conversion for 1st row
    dataRow = conv(cols)        # convert each data string
    dataset.append(dataRow)     # then append it
```

Then, the data are in list of list with proper data conversion.

```
print(dataset)
[['ID', 'Color', 'Brand', 'Price', 'Outstanding', 'Type'], ['02', 'Blue', 'Audi', 200.12, True, 2], ['06', 'Red', 'BMW', 2357.13, True, 1], ['13', 'Black', 'Ford', 252676.12, False, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def list_format():    
    
    lt= """ID, Color, Brand, Price, Outstanding, Type
02, Blue, Audi, 200.12, True, 2
06, Red, BMW, 2357.13, True, 1
13, Black, Ford, 252676.12, False, 5"""   
           
    
    result_list=[ i.split(',') for i in lt.split('\n')]   
    
    
    for i,val in enumerate(result_list):
              
        for k,v in enumerate(val):
            
            result_list[i][k]= result_list[i][k].replace(' ','')
            
            if result_list[i][k].isdigit() and k==0:
                
                result_list[i][k]=int(result_list[i][k])
            if k==3 and i!=0:
                
                result_list[i][k]=float(result_list[i][k])
            if k==4 and i!=0:
                
                result_list[i][k]=bool(result_list[i][k])
                
            
    
    print(result_list)

list_format()

[['ID', 'Color', 'Brand', 'Price', 'Outstanding', 'Type'], [2, 'Blue', 'Audi', 200.12, True, '2'], [6, 'Red', 'BMW', 2357.13, True, '1'], [13, 'Black', 'Ford', 252676.12, True, '5']]
```